# Referencing two String Lists to perform calculations

Tags: c#, algorithm, list

I am struggling trying to relate two string lists (they are called "List A" and "Pairs"). My aim is to calculate a determinant formed by the points in list A referenced in the list "Pairs".

The lists look like this:

**ListA (string)**

```
[0]: "30 10 0," //These represent the coordinates x,y,z of a point
[1]: "50 10 0,"
[2]: "40 10 0,"
[3]: "10 10 0,"
[4]: "20 10 0,"
[5]: "60 10 0,"
[6]: "70 20 0,"
[7]: "75 15 0,"
[8]: "100 10 0,"
[9]: "80 10 0,"
```

**List Pairs (string)**

```
[0]: {5 4}  //This indicates that the segment is formed by the points 5 and 4 in the List A
[1]: {0 1}
[2]: {6 7}
[3]: {6 5}
[4]: {9 6}
[5]: {2 3}
[6]: {8 9}
```

However, I need to follow a particular logic doing this because I need to populate two lists depending on the value of the determinant. They are called **"SegmentColl"** and **"PointsColl"**. See the explanation of this and an illustrative example below:

EXPLANATION

```
Given two generic segments a---------b and c---------d (stored in INT list pairs) and (ax,ay,az),(bx,by,bz),(cx,cy,cz),(dx,dy,dz) coordinates of such points 
(stored in INT list A) the following conditions must be checked:

DET(a,b,c)= 0
DET(a,b,d)= 0

I have to compare each of the segments with the other ones and if both determinants are = 0 then I add the segment's indices to a list called
“segmentColl” and the points in List A that are referred by such indices in a list called “pointsColl”. 



Example:

i) Compare segment(0) which is {5,4} in the "pairs" list against segment(1) which is {0 1}:

    DET[5,4,0]=DET{[60 10 0], [20 10 0], [30, 10, 0]} = 0   (See the formula of the determinant in the struct Point)
    DET(5,4,1)= DET{[60 10 0], [20 10 0] , [50, 10, 0]} =0

    Both determinants are = 0 so:

    1) I add the segment {0 1} to the FIRST row in INT LIST called “segmentColl” 

       SegmentColl= {[0,1],[ , ],[ , ],[ , ]} 

    2) I add the points represented by these indices {[20 20 0] [40 20 0]} to the FIRST row in INT LIST called “pointsColl”. 

       PointsColl= {[20 20 0] [40 20 0] , [...] [...] , [...] [...] , [...] [...]} 

ii) Compare segment (0) against segment (2) doing DET(5,4,6) and DET(5,4,7). In this case
    the determinants /=0 so they are not added to the FIRST row of “segmentColl” and “pointsColl”. 

    We keep on doing this for segment(0) against segment(3), then segment(0) against segment(4) and so on.

iii) Once segment(0) have been compared against all the other segments we move onto the next segment (1) and we do the same as with 
     segment (0). This will populate the SECOND row of the lists “segmentColl” and “pointsColl”.

     Note: at this point we will also compare segment(1) with segment(0) again because I want it to be in the SECOND row of the lists if 
     the determinant is zero (which is the case).


We will repeat this process so each segment has been compared with ALL the others.  

The expected result is:

SegmentColl:

{[0,1],[2,3],[5,4],[8,9]} // These four segments are collinear (det=0)
{[6,7],[9,6]} // These two segments are collinear (det=0)


PointsColl:
{[20 20 0] [40 20 0] , [...] [...] , [...] [...] , [...] [...]}  // The points represented by the 4 segments in segmentColl (row 0)
{[70 20 0] [75 15 0] , [...] [...]}                  // The points represented by the two segments in segmentColl (row 1)
```

My code is not very good but I think that the structs in there can be helpful, specially when it comes to calculate the determinant. :

```
using System;    
using System.Collections.Generic;


//This struct have been previously used to define the List "pairs"

struct Pair    
{
public int X { get; set; }
public int Y { get; set; }
public Pair(int x, int y)

    : this()
{
    X = x;
    Y = y;
}

public override string ToString()
{
    return String.Format("{0} {1}", this.X, this.Y);
}
}

// This struct has been previously used to define the points in List A and to provide a way to 
// calculate the determinants
struct Point
{
public readonly int X;
public readonly int Y;
public readonly int Z;

public Point(int x, int y, int z)
{
    X = x;
    Y = y;
    Z = z;
}

public override string ToString()
{
    return String.Format("{0} {1} {2},", X, Y, Z);
}

private static double Determinant(Point a, Point b, Point c)
{
    return (b.Y - a.Y) * (c.Z - a.Z) + (b.Z - a.Z) * (c.X - a.X) + (b.X - a.X) * (c.Y - a.Y) - (b.Z - a.Z) * (c.Y - a.Y) - (b.X - a.X) * (c.Z - a.Z) - (b.Y - a.Y) * (c.X - a.X);
}

public static bool Collinear(Point a, Point b, Point c)
{
    return Determinant(a, b, c) == 0.0;
}

public static Point FromString(string p)
{
    string[] items = p.Replace(",", "").Split(' ');
    int[] coords = new int[3];
    for (int i = 0; i < 3; i++) coords[i] = int.Parse(items[i]);
    return new Point(coords[0], coords[1], coords[2]);
}
}



class Program
{
static void Main()

{
    #region String Lists Input

    // This list represent the x,y,z coordinates of points. 
    var ListA = new List<string>();
    ListA.Add("30 10 0,");
    ListA.Add("50 10 0,");
    ListA.Add("40 10 0,");
    ListA.Add("10 10 0,");
    ListA.Add("20 10 0,");
    ListA.Add("60 10 0,");
    ListA.Add("70 20 0,");
    ListA.Add("75 15 0,");
    ListA.Add("100 10 0,");
    ListA.Add("80 10 0,");


    //This list have information about the connectivity of the points (indexes in List A forming the edges). For example 
    //the first pair (5,4) refers to the points "60 10 0," and "20 10 0," in List A.
    var pairs = new List<Pair>();
    pairs.Add(new Pair(5, 4));
    pairs.Add(new Pair(0, 1));
    pairs.Add(new Pair(6, 7));
    pairs.Add(new Pair(6, 5));
    pairs.Add(new Pair(9, 6));
    pairs.Add(new Pair(2, 3));
    pairs.Add(new Pair(8, 9));

    #endregion


// Code goes here as per explanation


    Console.ReadKey(); 

}}
```

I am a little bit lost trying to reference both lists and setting up the code to make this work.

If you could help me on this that would be great!

Many thanks!!

Comment: Why was this downvoted? Just because it's a hard question to follow/answer doesn't mean it's bad. :|

Comment: Can you show the code that you tried to write?

Comment: @alykins you can always suggest an edit if you think you can clarify it....

Comment: The post has been edited, I hope it is clearer now. I have also added the code I have. Thanks!!!

Comment: The first thing you need is a function that will create a `Point` from one of your strings like `{30 10 0}`. That way you can create an array of `Point` structures from your `ListA`. Then you need a function that will give you the correct `Point` structure from an index. That way, you can get the points for a `Pair` by writing `Point x = PointFromIndex(pair.X); Point y = PointFromIndex(pair.Y);` It looks like you have a good idea what to do with the values after that.

Comment: I don't understand the comment you have in the second list, where the pair is `5 4`, but the comment says, "`//This indicates that the segment is formed by the points 7 and 4`". How does `5 4` relate to `7 4`?

Comment: Sorry it was a mistake, I meant 5 4 (that is [60 10 0] and [20 10 0] in List A) not 7 4. I have corrected it now. Thanks.

Comment: @JimMischel - Thanks for your kind response. Just wondering, how do you create function that will give you the correct Point structure from an index?